# Write an executable .sh file with Java for OSX

Tags: java, shell, scripting, executable, sh

So I am trying to write an .sh file that will be executable, this is how I'm currently writing it:

```
Writer output = null;

try {
  output = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(file2));
  output.write(shellScriptContent);
  output.close();
} catch (IOException ex) {
  Logger.getLogger(PunchGUI.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
}
```

So that writes the file just fine, but it is not executable.  Is there a way to change the executable status when I write it?

Edit: To further clarify, I am trying to make it execute by default, so that for instance, if you double clicked the generated file, it would automatically execute.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You'd need to chmod it, and you can probably do it by exec'ing a system command like such:

Really all you'd need is to fire off something like this:

```
Runtime.getRuntime().exec("chmod u+x "+FILENAME);
```

But if you want to keep track of it more explicitly can capture stdin / stderr then something more like:

```
Process p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("chmod u+x "+FILENAME);
BufferedReader stdInput = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(p.getInputStream()));    
BufferedReader stdError = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(p.getErrorStream()));
```

Which I got from here: 
http://www.devdaily.com/java/edu/pj/pj010016/pj010016.shtml

**Update:**

Test program:

```
package junk;
import java.io.BufferedWriter;
import java.io.FileWriter;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.Writer;

public class Main{
  private String scriptContent = '#!/bin/bash \n echo "yeah toast!" > /tmp/toast.txt';
  public void doIt(){
    try{
      Writer output = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter("/tmp/toast.sh"));
      output.write(scriptContent);
      output.close();
      Runtime.getRuntime().exec("chmod u+x /tmp/toast.sh");
    }catch (IOException ex){}
  }

  public static void main(String[] args){
    Main m = new Main();
    m.doIt();
  }

}
```

On linux if you open up a file browser and double click on /tmp/toast.sh and choose to run it, it should generate a text file /tmp/toast.txt with the words 'yeah toast'.  I assume Mac would do the same since it's BSD under the hood.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion!  Will this also make it automatically execute when double clicked?

Comment: It should, assuming the user running the java program is the same who will run the shell script.  Otherwise you could adjust the chmod to a+x which means all users have execute permission.  I did a small test program on linux and it worked for me.

Comment: You saved the day dude, i was getting around how to execute a script from within java and turns out all i needed to do was make it executable via the `chmod` command ! Thanks

Answer (score 27):

You can call [`File.setExecutable()`](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/io/File.html#setExecutable(boolean)) to set the owner's executable bit for the file, which might be sufficient for your case. Or you can just `chmod` it yourself with a system call with `Process`.

Alas, full-powered programmatic alteration of file permissions isn't available until Java 7. It'll be part of the New IO feature set, which you can read more about [**here**](http://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=203).

Comment: Thanks, but unfortunately, I'm working with 1.5.  It has to have pretty broad compatibility for OSX, and most people don't have 1.6.

Comment: In that case, you're stuck with my alternate solution of using chmod with a system call. Sorry!

Answer (score 6):

In Java 7 you can call [`Files.setPosixFilePermissions`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/nio/file/Files.html#setPosixFilePermissions(java.nio.file.Path,%20java.util.Set)). Here is an example:

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.nio.file.Files;
import java.nio.file.Path;
import java.nio.file.Paths;
import java.nio.file.attribute.PosixFilePermission;
import java.util.Set;

class FilePermissionExample {
  public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
    final Path filepath = Paths.get("path", "to", "file.txt");
    final Set<PosixFilePermission> permissions = Files.getPosixFilePermissions(filepath);
    permissions.add(PosixFilePermission.OWNER_EXECUTE);
    Files.setPosixFilePermissions(filepath, permissions);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

On Mac OS X, besides chmod +x, you have to give a `.command` extension to your shell script if you want to launch it with a double-click.

Answer (score 1):

[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/664432/java-how-do-i-programmatically-change-file-permissions/664453#664453) I wrote for the question [how do I programmatically change file permissions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/664432/java-how-do-i-programmatically-change-file-permissions) shows a chmod example via a native call using jna, which should work on Mac OS X.