# how to make files executable using jre 1.5?

Tags: java, file

I wnat to give executable permssisons to a file using java 5 . I know that jre6 File has the api's for changing permissions. How to do it using java 5 . Any apache commons is there

Comment: Kind of ambigious.  Are you asking if you can compile a java class file into an exe on windows?

Comment: which operating system ?

Comment: possible duplicate of [\[java\] how do i programmatically change file permissions?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/664432/java-how-do-i-programmatically-change-file-permissions)

Comment: Andreas_D's link shows how to use JNA to invoke chmod as well as how to exec it externally, both of which will solve this problem, so I would agree this is a dupe.

Answer (score 1):

For Linux/Unix: You can use [Runtime.getRuntime().exec()](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/lang/Runtime.html#exec%28java.lang.String%5B%5D%29) to execute [/bin/chmod](http://linux.die.net/man/1/chmod).

Comment: This should work on BSD as well, and of course on Windows there is no executable flag.