# NTFS Files Permissions in Java 6

Tags: java, permissions, file-permissions, java-6

It's possible to retrieve all permissions of a file in NTFS FileSystem with Java 6? I know in Java 7 it's very simple. Anyone know some framework to do that?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't believe that Java 6 has the underlying OS hooks to handle this. Any library or code sample that you find to do this is going to have to use native code or something like Runtime.exec(). If you really need this functionality, you might just want to write a function that shells out and calls the appropriate Windows command to retrieve these permissions.

Also, take a look at this question for a good conversation on a similar subject: [How do i programmatically change file permissions?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/664432/how-do-i-programmatically-change-file-permissions)