# Getting java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: android.os.FileUtils.getFatVolumeId in 4.2.2 and later OS

Tags: java, android, service, crash, nosuchmethoderror

I am facing issue in service onCreate() when trying to get SD Card id. Using FileUtils class of android.os package from src-external/android-core.

```
mCardId =
  FileUtils.getFatVolumeId(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getPath());
```

Crash Log :

```
12-31 19:55:25.804: E/AndroidRuntime(1235):
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: android.os.FileUtils.getFatVolumeId 12-31
19:55:25.804: E/AndroidRuntime(1235):   at
cloudtv.android.cs.service.MediaPlaybackService.onCreate(MediaPlaybackService.java:198)
12-31 19:55:25.804: E/AndroidRuntime(1235):     at
android.app.ActivityThread.handleCreateService(ActivityThread.java:2572)
12-31 19:55:25.804: E/AndroidRuntime(1235):     at
android.app.ActivityThread.access$1800(ActivityThread.java:135) 12-31
19:55:25.804: E/AndroidRuntime(1235):   at
android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1278)
12-31 19:55:25.804: E/AndroidRuntime(1235):     at
android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 12-31
19:55:25.804: E/AndroidRuntime(1235):   at
android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136) 12-31 19:55:25.804:
E/AndroidRuntime(1235):     at
android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5017) 12-31
19:55:25.804: E/AndroidRuntime(1235):   at
java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method) 12-31
19:55:25.804: E/AndroidRuntime(1235):   at
java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515) 12-31 19:55:25.804:
E/AndroidRuntime(1235):     at
com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:779)
12-31 19:55:25.804: E/AndroidRuntime(1235):     at
com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:595) 12-31
19:55:25.804: E/AndroidRuntime(1235):   at
dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[`FileUtils`](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/master/core/java/android/os/FileUtils.java) is a platform-internal class, annotated with `@hide`. You should not be using it.

Comment: Thanks for quick response, i am using it and working fine but issue is only from 4.2.2 and later devices.

Comment: @BipinVayalu: At most, it is "working fine" on the devices you have tried. There is no requirement that any device have `FileUtils`, let alone any specific method on it. And, as you are discovering, there is no requirement for Google to continue offering it.