# Copy and execute native service binary & check logs

Tags: java, android, shell, android-ndk, java-native-interface

I'm building a application which makes use of a Native service binary file.

Now my requirements are:

Place the native service binary file in the assets folder of application.

1. When the application runs, copy this native file in the device (path like `getExternalFilesDir(null)`)
2. Execute this binary file within the device.
3. Check if the file has been succesfully executed in logs.

Now to copy the file, I've used:

```
private void copyAssets() {
    AssetManager assetManager = getAssets();
    String[] files = null;
    try {
        files = assetManager.list("");
    } catch (IOException e) {
        Log.e("tag", "Failed to get asset file list.", e);
    }
    for (String filename : files) {
        if (filename.equals("native-file")) { // native-file is the file name present is assets folder
            InputStream in = null;
            OutputStream out = null;
            try {
                in = assetManager.open(filename);
                File outFile = new File(getExternalFilesDir(null), filename);
                out = new FileOutputStream(outFile);
                copyFile(in, out);
                in.close();
                in = null;
                out.flush();
                out.close();
                out = null;

            } catch (IOException e) {
                Log.e("tag", "Failed to copy asset file: " + filename, e);
            }
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

And after copying to execute the file I'm using:

```
File sdCard = getExternalFilesDir(null); // directory where native file is placed
Process proc = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("sh -c shell " + sdCard.getAbsolutePath() + "/native-file "+ sdCard.getAbsolutePath() +"/native-file.log\" "); // command 1
proc = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("sh -c less " + sdCard.getAbsolutePath() +"/native-file.log\""); // command 2
```

Issues:

1. How can I make sure that the file is placed.
2. How to make sure the that it is executed. Because I'm not able to find and log files (native-file.log) when I run the application.

PS - I can not provide my JNI file due to proprietry issues. So i guess we can use an opensource [asl](https://code.google.com/p/android-screenshot-library/) library.(there is a native file by name asl-native)

Comment: You can not execute files in `/sdcard`, the platform prevents setting files in SD card to execute mode.

Comment: @shoerat any work around?

Answer (score 2):

Your current code is not too far off, but there's a few details you need to take care of:

1. As already have been commented, you can't execute files that you've put in `/sdcard`. You can however execute files in the internal memory. Thus, instead of `getExternalFilesDir(null)`, use `getFilesDir()`
2. After copying the executable to the target directory, you need to make it executable. You can either run `Runtime.getRuntime().exec("chmod 755 " + getFilesDir()  + "/native-file").waitFor();` or try using the private `android.os.FileUtils` class (as in https://stackoverflow.com/a/11408378/3115956).
3. You don't need any extra "sh -c shell" when starting your app, this is enough: `Process proc = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(getFilesDir()  + "/native-file");`
4. If you want to read stdout/stderr output from your executable (to verify that it run correctly), you can do e.g. this:

   ```
   InputStream stdout = proc.getInputStream();
   InputStream stderr = proc.getErrorStream();
   BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(stdout));
   String line;
   while ((line = br.readLine()) != null)
       System.out.println("stdout: " + line);
   br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(stderr));
   while ((line = br.readLine()) != null)
       System.out.println("stderr: " + line);
   ```

To simplify steps 1 and 2, and to avoid having to take care of the different architectures for native binaries yourself, you could rename your command line executable to match the pattern `lib<something>.so` and put it in the `libs/<abi>` directory in your project. Then it will be picked up by the APK packager and be packaged like any native library. To execute it, you can simply do `Process proc = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(getApplicationInfo().nativeLibraryDir + "/libnative-file.so");`

Comment: Sorry for delay & thank you. The permission change works I guess because the waitfor() command is returning 0. But `exec(getFilesDir()  + "/native-file");` is returning `1 & no stdout is printed but stderr is printing `stderr: Error while starting server (errno=13): Permission denied`. I tried using asl native file mentioned in my question. Any suggestions? And also how to rename my command to .so, can you please explain.

Comment: First you can check whether your native binary actually can run on your device at all - you can try to send it to the device and run it using `adb push native-file /data/local/tmp` and `adb shell /data/local/tmp/native-file` - if this doesn't work, something is wrong with your file (outside of the scope of this question). To rename it to .so, do `mkdir -p libs/armeabi` and `cp assets/native-file libs/armeabi/libnative-file.so`. You need to replace `armeabi` with the right ABI name the binary is built for, that the device uses.