# "Generated servlet error: <class> cannot be resolved to a type" in page

Tags: java, jsp, exception, jna

I was trying to implement JNA. I have used the following code for the testing purpose. Now I am getting an exception. Please correct me if I am using an incorrect method or if there are any problems in my testing code.

My reference tutorials were [this](http://www.experts-exchange.com/Programming/Languages/Java/A_1498-File-permissions-with-Java.html) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/664432/how-do-i-programmatically-change-file-permissions)

My class FileModifierLinux:

```
import com.sun.jna.Library;
import com.sun.jna.Native;

public class FileModifierLinux {
     CLibrary libc = (CLibrary) Native.loadLibrary("c", CLibrary.class);
    public void Update(String pth) {
        libc.chmod(pth, 0755);
    }
}
interface CLibrary extends Library {
    public int chmod(String path, int mode);
}
```

My page:

```
<%

try
{
    FileModifierLinux flx=new FileModifierLinux();
    String pathX = getServletContext().getRealPath("/testpage.jsp");
    flx.Update(pathX);
    out.println("No Exception");
}
catch(Exception exp)
{
    out.println("exp :"+exp);
}
%>
```

Exception:

```
org.apache.jasper.JasperException: Unable to compile class for JSP

An error occurred at line: 15 in the jsp file: /index.jsp
Generated servlet error:
FileModifierLinux cannot be resolved to a type

An error occurred at line: 15 in the jsp file: /index.jsp
Generated servlet error:
FileModifierLinux cannot be resolved to a type

    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.handleJspException(JspServletWrapper.java:510)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:375)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:314)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:264)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:802)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did you `import` the class in the `index.jsp`? like:

```
<%@page import="com.somepackage.FileModifierLinux "%>
```

Comment: Sorry that was my mistake. Thanks for your help