# How to hijack files from clearcase from eclipse plugin

Tags: eclipse, plugins, clearcase

I am developing a component which generates code based on templates inside java class. The project use clearcase as SCM. After the code update, the files are in read-only state. If i am adding anything to any java class, i have to make it hijack and paste the source code templates inside the class. Let's suppose the jAutoDoc plugin which is used for adding comment. If user select a class, click on generate comment. The comment will not paste if the file is not in write mode.

Clearcase Plugin Vendor : IBM Rational.

Eclipse Version : 3.5

Please help. Is there any way to do hijack a file from java code?

Thanks in advance..

Comment: I have added in my answer below a link to change the file attributes in Java.

Comment: Is my answer relevant? Did you need more information?

Comment: Its' working.. I am just trying to find the way to get the eclipse preference for a Class and set the read-only mode to false..

Comment: So you want to make sure Eclipse will set a certain type of files in read-write mode when it needs to modify them, right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks VonC.

For making a java file in write mode through eclipse JDT API. This method will set the preference "read only" of the resource to "false".

```
private static void setCompilationUnitWriteMode(ICompilationUnit cu) throws CoreException {

        ResourceAttributes resourceAttributes = cu.getResource().getResourceAttributes();

        if (resourceAttributes != null) {
              // Setting Writemode true
            resourceAttributes.setReadOnly(false);
        cu.getResource().setResourceAttributes(resourceAttributes);
    }
  }
```

For Non Java Resource

First create the IFile object, set the preference "read only" of the resource to "false".

```
       IFile file = path.getFile() 

        file.getFile().getResourceAttributes();

        if (resourceAttributes != null) {
            resourceAttributes.setReadOnly(false);
            file.setResourceAttributes(resourceAttributes);
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Hijacking files only means making them read - write through an OS-based operation. (for snapshot view only, not dynamic ones)

The question is though: do you need to version your classes completed by your plugin?
Because in that case, a `cleartool checkout` is more appropriate.

Otherwise, read write is enough, [changing file attribute through java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/664432/how-do-i-programmatically-change-file-permissions).