# Set read permisstion for directory

Tags: java, permissions, javafx

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do i programmatically change file permissions?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/664432/how-do-i-programmatically-change-file-permissions)

I want to set read permission for some directory. Because i want to use [list() method from java.io.File](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/File.html#list%28%29), but when i print for example this:

```
System.out.println(fileDir.list());
```

i get "null", according to the documentation it may mean that I do not have permissions to the directory, where the file is located.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use [JNA](https://github.com/twall/jna/) to call a native C library (as an alternative to using JNI).

The only problem with JNA is that it has a higher process time than JNA, so it becomes impractical if you try to modify a large number of files/directories.

**Edit for code**

```
import com.sun.jna.Library;
import com.sun.jna.Native;

public class ChmodTest {
    private static LinkedOSLibrary linkedLibrary = 
        (LinkedOSLibrary ) Native.loadLibrary("c", LinkedOSLibrary.class);

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        linkedLibrary.chmod("/path/to/file", 0755);
    }
}

interface LinkedOSLibrary extends Library {
    public int chmod(String path, int mode);
}
```

[Source](http://www.experts-exchange.com/Programming/Languages/Java/A_1498-File-permissions-with-Java.html)