# How to check write permissions of a directory in java? Can we change it?

Tags: java, file-io

I am using the code below, but it’s not working. The method `canWrite()` is not working, even if changing the rights for writing for a directory.

```
File file = new File(fc.getSelectedFile().getAbsolutePath());
// fc is a FileChooser object
if(f.canWrite()) 
{
  // write access
} 
else 
{
  // no write access
}
```

I have also tried:

```
try 
{
    AccessController.checkPermission(new FilePermission("/tmp/*", "read,write"));
    System.out.println("Good");
    // Has permission
}
catch (SecurityException e) 
{
// Does not have permission
System.out.println("Bad");
}
```

Comment: For change the permissions 

 Look at this link :- "http://stackoverflow.com/questions/664432/how-do-i-programmatically-change-file-permissions"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `File.canWrite()` method is behaving as its specification says it should:

> Returns: `true` if and only if the file system actually contains **a file** denoted by this abstract pathname and the application is allowed to write to the file; `false` otherwise.

(Emphasis added).

It is returning `false` because the object is not a file.

---

If you are using Java 7 (or later), one solution would be to use [`Files.getAttribute`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/nio/file/Files.html#getAttribute%28java.nio.file.Path,%20java.lang.String,%20java.nio.file.LinkOption...%29) to retrieve the relevant attribute(s) to determine the access.  Note that the attribute you use may be operating system specific.  (I'm sure Google could find examples for you.)