# Access permission ,group and user of a file on linux pc in java

Tags: java

How can i get and create access permission ,group and user of a file on linux pc in java.

Comment: And what have you tried?

Answer (score 0):

If you're using Java 7, you should be able to use the [POSIX functionality](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/nio/file/Files.html) to do this.  Specifically, the `getPosixFilePermissions` method should be what you're looking for.  See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/664432/how-do-i-programmatically-change-file-permissions) for more information.

Comment: thank for your answer.but i want to use this getPosixFilePermissions method in java 6

Comment: It's not available in Java 6.  Can you upgrade to Java 7?

Comment: It`s not available to use java 7 in our project because of our development framework is base on java 6.

Answer (score 0):

```
package Test.Dir.Onlinux;

import java.io.BufferedReader;  
import java.io.IOException;  
import java.io.InputStream;  
import java.io.InputStreamReader;  
import ch.ethz.ssh2.Connection;  
import ch.ethz.ssh2.Session;  
import ch.ethz.ssh2.StreamGobbler;  
import java.lang.System;

public class TestDirOnLinux {


    public static void main(String[] args) {

        String linuxCommands[] = { "stat -c %U ", "stat -c %G ", "stat -c %A ", "stat -c %a " };
        String fileName = "/home/zmt/UberSVN";
        excuteLinuxCommand("192.168.0.26", "root", "ace@dir", linuxCommands[0] + fileName);
        excuteLinuxCommand("192.168.0.26", "root", "ace@dir", linuxCommands[1] + fileName);
        excuteLinuxCommand("192.168.0.26", "root", "ace@dir", linuxCommands[2] + fileName);
        excuteLinuxCommand("192.168.0.26", "root", "ace@dir", linuxCommands[3] + fileName);
    }

    public static void excuteLinuxCommand(String ipAddress, String userName, String password, String linuxCommands) {

        boolean isAuthenticated = false;

        try {
            // Connection conn = new Connection(hostname);
            Connection conn = new Connection(ipAddress);
            conn.connect();
            // isAuthenticated = conn.authenticateWithPassword(username,
            // password);
            isAuthenticated = conn.authenticateWithPassword(userName, password);

            if (isAuthenticated == false)
                throw new IOException("Authentication failed.");

            Session sess = conn.openSession();

            // sess.execCommand("shutdown -h now");
            sess.execCommand(linuxCommands);

            InputStream stdout = new StreamGobbler(sess.getStdout());
            InputStream stderr = new StreamGobbler(sess.getStderr());

            InputStreamReader insrout = new InputStreamReader(stdout);
            InputStreamReader insrerr = new InputStreamReader(stderr);

            BufferedReader stdoutReader = new BufferedReader(insrout);
            BufferedReader stderrReader = new BufferedReader(insrerr);

            while (true) {
                String line = stdoutReader.readLine();`enter code here`
                if (line == null) {
                    break;
                }
                System.out.println(line);
            }

            while (true) {
                String line = stderrReader.readLine();
                if (line == null) {
                    break;
                }
                System.out.println(line);
            }

            sess.close();

            conn.close();

        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace(System.err);
            System.exit(2);
        }
    }
}

    enter code here
```