# Prevent deletion of files

Tags: java, image, file, jar, delete-file

I have a jar file that downloads images from my server and also creates some local files. I have to transfer this file to the client. I want to know how can I prevent the user from deleting the folders or any other file created by this jar, as downloading again the whole set of images would be a huge overhead. The user must only be able to execute the jar.

Comment: Block permissions for the user on the folder and run the jar using a user with more privileges over this folder.

Comment: @LuiggiMendoza I am only supposed to provide the jar. I won't have access user's system. Can I do something in my code that can help me do that? I thought of writing a backup utility that can keep track of deletion but that again needs to depend on a file which user can delete.

Comment: Then you're out of luck. Just notify users that if they delete the files, then they will have a bad time...

Comment: You need to download and creates some local files in the Application data folder. Which is by default hidden in windows.

Comment: @LuiggiMendoza  Kind of thought so. Thanks, anyway, for your input.

Comment: @aksappy That is the question. It's user's choice and that's why I wanted something in my code only that can prevent any accidental data loss.

Comment: Deploy the lot using [Java Web Start](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/java-web-start/info).  Put the images (without compression) into Jar files that are marked as 'lazy' download.  The download of images will be done only when necessary and be locally cached.  This does not fit your primary requirement of "don't let the user delete them" because that job is now the responsibility of the JRE & the Java Control Panel, however it is a sensible way to deploy such resources.

Comment: @AndrewThompson The downloads are dynamic. The user must be able to manually browse through the image folder. Everytime some image is added to the server, my jar file checks for it and downloads it to the images folder. So, whether or not to download an image is by default my code's responsibility. Does java web start still applies here?

Comment: If the images can be put into Jar, and the JNLP (launch file) altered it might do the trick.  But just as an aside, no software which imported images that it would not let me delete, would result in the entire application being deleted.  After all, it is my local file-system that is being clogged up with images, and my choice as to what stays or goes.  No 'ifs', no 'buts'.

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to find out what system it is. For that use this

`System.getProperty("os.name");`

Based on the system, use either NIO or POSIX in JDK 7 or [jna](https://github.com/twall/jna/)

For examples, have a look at this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/664432/how-do-i-programmatically-change-file-permissions)

Answer (score 0):

I had to write some backing up code to restore files if deleted. A rather specific solution to my problem.