# Apache httpd can't serve files generated by Tomcat

Tags: java, apache, jsp, tomcat, permissions

I've got virtual hosts running on Apache with Tomcat running for JSP pages. Tomcat is runnign as the tomcat user, with a nobody group. There are files generated by Tomcat that get created as the tomcat:nobody user but then these files cannot be found by apache to serve them to the web user, so I get 404 errors.

**NOTE: The JSPs are working correctly. It is the files created by Java that then are not accessible.**

If I manually change the tomcat:nobody files to webuser:webuser (or whatever the virtual host user is), then apache finds the files. However, this obviously cannot be done manually for an on-demand process.

How can I get these automatically generated files to load via Apache if they are created inside tomcat?

Answer (score -1):

You need to use the tomcat ajp connector, mod_jk.

See http://tomcat.apache.org/connectors-doc/webserver_howto/apache.html

Comment: Thank you for your reply -- The connector is working as JSPs run fine. It's the files created from within the JSP/Java engine that then cannot be found by apache.

Comment: Ah, I see.  I guess you'll have to generate them with permissions that allows apache to read them.  See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/664432/how-do-i-programmatically-change-file-permissions