# permission denied write with USB pen drive

Tags: java, android

this is my AndroidManifest.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.abc2"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.1.8" >
    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="8"
        android:targetSdkVersion="18" />

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.DISABLE_KEYGUARD" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" /> 
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
```

and i m trying to copy the apps's database to USB pendrive, last time are using SD card, it is working fine, but after i have change the SD card path to `/mnt/sda/sda2` it is error permission denied, `/mnt/sda/sda2` is the USB pendrive path

this is the copy file function to copy the database to pendrive

```
private void copyFile(String inputPath, String inputFile, String outputPath) {

        InputStream in = null;
        OutputStream out = null;
        try {

            //create output directory if it doesn't exist
            File dir = new File (outputPath); 
            if (!dir.exists())
            {
                dir.mkdirs();
            }


            in = new FileInputStream(inputPath + inputFile);        
            out = new FileOutputStream(outputPath + inputFile);

            byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
            int read;
            while ((read = in.read(buffer)) != -1) {
                out.write(buffer, 0, read);
            }
            in.close();
            in = null;

                // write the output file (You have now copied the file)
                out.flush();
            out.close();
            out = null;  
            Toast.makeText(UltilityActivity.this, "Export successful!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

        }  catch (FileNotFoundException fnfe1) {
            Log.e("tag", fnfe1.getMessage());
            Toast.makeText(UltilityActivity.this, "Export failed", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
                catch (Exception e) {
            Log.e("tag", e.getMessage());
            Toast.makeText(UltilityActivity.this, "Export failed", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }

    }    
}
```

this is how i call the copyfile function

```
copyFile("/data/data/com.example.abc2/databases/","DB_BusData","/mnt/sda/sda2/");
```

last time is copied to SD card , with this code

```
copyFile("/data/data/com.example.abc2/databases/","DB_BusData","/mnt/sdcard/");
```

copied to SD card are working, but USB pendrive errror with :-

```
03-10 10:58:13.204: D/MainActivity(1832): open failed: EACCES (Permission denied)
03-10 10:58:13.204: D/MainActivity(1832): java.io.IOException: open failed: EACCES (Permission denied)
```

it is need to mount USB drive? can i mount in programmatically ? how? please give me an example?

Comment: Just check the Read/Write permission of `/mnt/sda/sda2/` over ADB.

Comment: @user370305 Yea, i have found `/mnt/sda/sda2/` dont have write permission. any solution to set when the apps started automatically set the path with write permission??

Comment: Actually its a OEM vendor specific entry for Hardware. I don't think you can change it programmatically if its restricted. As some vendor gives Read Only permission to USB.

Comment: @user370305 then how to change manually?

Comment: you need a root permission for that.

Comment: @user370305 http://stackoverflow.com/questions/664432/how-do-i-programmatically-change-file-permissions , this answer are not able to change file permission?please have a look

Comment: Yes, I knew. But on arm devices you need a root permission to change file permission.

Comment: @user370305 if i got the root permission, and then every devices i need to re-permission it. right?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

in Android OS, Usually USB pendrive will know as SD card,
But, the permission in `Androidmanifest.xml` need to declare different permission,
USB external storage need media enable permission like below :-

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_MEDIA_STORAGE" />
```

Comment: That permission is system-only, so it requires a rooted device.