# Give the permission in java to write on everywhere on the Hard Drive

Tags: java, nio, securitymanager

I am developing an application in `java` using the classes form the package `nio`.

I would like to know how to provide the program the rights to write everywhere on the hard drive.

because it works on my home directory but not everywhere on the hard drive.

Comment: Ever though It's not given full rights for a reason? Especially if you are going to be giving this out to companies/etc (other than that, I suppose you could allow access **only** if they have admin privileges already)?

Comment: This will be determined by the access rights of whoever runs your application. How you control that is an OS-dependent issue (and not on-topic for Stack Overflow).

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do i programmatically change file permissions?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/664432/how-do-i-programmatically-change-file-permissions)

Comment: As long as you don't access that **one folder** that I don't... uhh.. have :O

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The permission is not associated with your program but with who (which account) runs this program, if it's being executed by a system account with administrator privileges then the program will have the power to perform I/O operations everywhere.

In linux you can grant 'sudo' access to non-root users, you can check if that would be an option for you, however, it seems like a risky scenario, you might want to study this use case and consider specifying the exact permissions you need based on your needs

If you are not sure who's running this program, you can verify the java process:

1. Search for a java.exe in your Windows environment
   (http://technet.microsoft.com/en-ie/sysinternals/bb896653.aspx)
2. Run `ps fuxa | grep java` in you linux terminal