# Java Programatically simulating chmod -R 755

Tags: java, file

I have a piece of code using which I create a new directory. 
I want to do a chmod -R 755 ./destDirectory

Way I am creating files is:

File destFile = new File("/home/destFile");
File oneFile = new File("home/destFile/1");

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/664432/how-do-i-programmatically-change-file-permissions

Comment: Can't you do this in the NIO2 Files/Paths API now

Comment: Is there a way to do it with java.io.file ?

Comment: @user966123 have you read the duplicate link or javadocs?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check out the [API documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/nio/file/Files.html) for the `java.no.file.Files` class, which has a variety of utility methods for setting attributes, permissions, and performing other actions not found in the java.io.File class.

You can use the `createDirectory(...)` method to set permissions upon creation, or the `setPosixFilePermissions(...)` method for an existing file or directory.