# How to give permission 700 and 770 to file & folder using java

Tags: java, permissions, chmod

I want to give the chmod 700 permission to a file using java.

Code I used

```
Set<PosixFilePermission> perms = new HashSet<PosixFilePermission>();
    perms.add(PosixFilePermission.OWNER_READ);
    perms.add(PosixFilePermission.OWNER_WRITE);
    perms.add(PosixFilePermission.OWNER_EXECUTE);
    //add group permissions
    perms.add(PosixFilePermission.GROUP_READ);
    perms.add(PosixFilePermission.GROUP_WRITE);
    perms.add(PosixFilePermission.GROUP_EXECUTE);

Path FilePathObject = Paths.get(fileDir.toString(),"fileRun.sh");
Files.setPosixFilePermissions(FilePathObject, perms);
```

But it is not setting permission correctly -

```
drwxrwsr-x   4 user group       94 Aug 12 05:45 scriptconfig
```

I tried this code as well to set the 700 permission -

```
    txtFilePath.toFile().setExecutable(false,true);
    txtFilePath.toFile().setReadable(false, true);
    txtFilePath.toFile().setWritable(false,true);
```

But this is also not working as per the expectation. Do we have any thing through which we can set these permissions.

Comment: A dirty way is this one: `Runtime.getRuntime().exec("chmod 770 <filename>");`

Comment: which java version are you using?

Comment: You can execute commands from within java like below    Process p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("unix command");

Comment: The code under "Code I used" will definitely not work, because you did not even specify the file path in that code.

Comment: Thanks for mentioning it out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This code Will be working, if you want to give 770 permission to a file -

```
Set<PosixFilePermission> perms = new HashSet<PosixFilePermission>();
perms.add(PosixFilePermission.OWNER_READ);
perms.add(PosixFilePermission.OWNER_WRITE);
perms.add(PosixFilePermission.OWNER_EXECUTE);
//add group permissions
perms.add(PosixFilePermission.GROUP_READ);
perms.add(PosixFilePermission.GROUP_WRITE);
perms.add(PosixFilePermission.GROUP_EXECUTE);

Path FilePathObject = Paths.get(fileDir.toString(),"fileRun.sh");
Files.setPosixFilePermissions(FilePathObject, perms);
```

> Note :  You have to create the directory before executing given
>   command then only it will work otherwise directory will be created
>   with default permissions.

First create the directory then you can use

> PosixFilePermission API introduced in Java 1.7.

`

Answer (score 1):

Simply try

```
txtFilePath.toFile().setExecutable(true);
txtFilePath.toFile().setReadable(true);
txtFilePath.toFile().setWritable(true);
```

else you can check below

[How do i programmatically change file permissions?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/664432/how-do-i-programmatically-change-file-permissions)

Comment: This only affects the user permissions, not group or other.