# Change file permissions programmatically

Tags: java, android, chmod

I have a method that copies a png file, but the file is created with permissions set to read only by owner. I want to change the permissions to 777. I'm not getting any errors, but the file permissions aren't changed.

```
private void SaveImage(Bitmap finalBitmap){
    String root = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().toString();
    File myDir = new File(root + "/Movies");
    String fname = desc +".mkv";
    File file = new File (myDir, fname);
    String chmod_path = (root + "/" +  fname);
    final File ch_file = new File(chmod_path);
    try {
        FileOutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(file);
        finalBitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 90, out);
        out.flush();
        out.close();
        ch_file.setReadable(true, false);
        ch_file.setExecutable(true, false);
        ch_file.setWritable(true, false);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

}
```

Comment: Why do you need this? It sounds quite shady.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do i programmatically change file permissions?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/664432/how-do-i-programmatically-change-file-permissions)

Comment: maybe remove the `final` declaration from your ch_file?

Comment: @arias_JC tried that without any luck.

Comment: @HopefullyHelpful The png file that is copied is used to "trick" plex into thinking its a video, but it doesn't work unless the permissions are at least read/execute by anyone.

Comment: Files don't need to be executable unless they are actual scripts.

Comment: @cricket_007 "The user account needs to have at least read and execute permission for the directories and content."- Plex Website

Comment: Are you running plex on your android device?

Comment: Anyways, you only need execute on the directory in order to list the contents. Execute does nothing on a file unless it's actually runnable

Comment: @cricket_007 No. I'm using the barcode scanner tool on my phone to get the name of the blu-ray. Then I'm making a "fake" video file with the same name. I then will copy all of those files and put them on my desktop for plex to scan.

Comment: Okay, then why do you think changing the file permissions on your Android device will affect the permissions on your server?