# How to change permissions to incoming file in linux using JAVA

Tags: java, linux, wso2, file-permissions, wso2-esb

**Objective**

I want that whenever someone uploads a file (name is **Accounts 0998.csv**) in **/opt/file/incoming** directory. Its permissions gets change to chmod 664 i.e **rw-rw-r** 
I am using linux.

I want to automate this process so I am writing a java program but its working

```
package com.reader.file;

import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;

public class GrantPermission
{
    public static void main( String[] args )
    {
        try {

          File file = new File("/opt/file/Accounts 0998.csv");

         if(file.exists()){
             System.out.println("File exists.");

            //using PosixFilePermission to set file permissions 664

            Set<PosixFilePermission> perms = new 

            HashSet<PosixFilePermission>();

            //add owners permission
            perms.add(PosixFilePermission.OWNER_READ);
            perms.add(PosixFilePermission.OWNER_WRITE);

            //add group permissions
            perms.add(PosixFilePermission.GROUP_READ);
            perms.add(PosixFilePermission.GROUP_WRITE);

            //add others permissions
            perms.add(PosixFilePermission.OTHERS_READ);

            Files.setPosixFilePermissions(file.toPath(), perms);

            } catch (IOException e) {

                e.printStackTrace();
            }
         }
         else{
              System.out.println("File does not exists.");
         }

        } catch (IOException e) {
          e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

**Additional Information**

I am using WSO2 ESB it first search for a file then If file exists then I want to change its permission (via using **Class mediator i.e JAVA**) and then move it to another directory but my GOAL is change file permissions to  **rw-rw-r**

Comment: "whenever someone uploads a file": how is this done? The default file permissions depend on the umask setting of the uploading process.

Comment: What do u mean by this? umask setting of the uploading process. In linux I have a username "fileuploader" When I upload a file from fileuploader the default permissions are rw-r-r but I want rw-rw-r and I want to automate this process.

Comment: I mean, better than correcting the permissions, make sure they are set correctly when the file is created. https://askubuntu.com/questions/44542/what-is-umask-and-how-does-it-work

Comment: I am not creating I am uploading a file. Will this link is still valid?

Comment: I don't get what you mean by "upload". Some process must accept the file over the network and create it on disk.

Comment: I connect to filezilla via sftp and I just copy my file from my machine to linux machine

Comment: Ok, in this case it is the ssh daemon that creates the file. Then it is not a good idea to change its umask because this would have global effects.

Comment: Yes. I don't want to change setting of linux server that is why using java

Comment: It's better to make sure the destination directory for saving your files is in the right mode(e.g. rwx...) before the uploading process started. It's will be risky  to allow the user process to change system settings.

Answer (score 0):

You can use NIO.2 if you are using java7 or later.

### See:

[How do i programmatically change file permissions?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/664432/how-do-i-programmatically-change-file-permissions)

```html
//if you need rw-rw-r  permissions 
public void setPermission(File file) throws IOException{
    Set<PosixFilePermission> perms = new HashSet<>();
    perms.add(PosixFilePermission.OWNER_READ);
    perms.add(PosixFilePermission.OWNER_WRITE);

    perms.add(PosixFilePermission.OTHERS_READ);
    perms.add(PosixFilePermission.OTHERS_WRITE);

    perms.add(PosixFilePermission.GROUP_READ);

    Files.setPosixFilePermissions(file.toPath(), perms);
}
```

Comment: You are still missing `Files.setPosixFilePermissions(file.toPath(), perms);`

Comment: I have added that