# Creating 600 (equivalent) file permission on windows using java code

Tags: java, windows, file, nio

I have tried to create a file with file permissions equivalent to 600 that is Read and write for owner and for all others no permissions what so ever. Works good using PosixFilePermission in unix, but in windows not able to achieve same. tried permissions setting using java nio and java Files class setRead setWrite methods. Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: check this answer, I think it fits to you: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13892920

Comment: Tried that but could not get expected behavior as ACL provides control only over owner's permissions. Thanks for the pointer:)