# How to create shared folder (public) in java

Tags: java, shared-directory

I need to create a public folder, shared with everyone from an application in java

Comment: On what operating system? Is it NFS mounted?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/664432/how-do-i-programmatically-change-file-permissions

Comment: On Windows 7 with support Windows nt and vista

Comment: tanks resolve problem

Answer (score 0):

Create batch file

@echo off
E:               ==>select drive(I used E drive), wher you want create a folder
mkdir test1               ==>you need to make a folder before to share and name it (ex:test1) 
net share test1=E:\test1/GRANT:domain\username,full  ==>share the folder using net share command
Pause ==> final step

and execute in java

[How do I run a batch file from my Java Application?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/615948/how-do-i-run-a-batch-file-from-my-java-application?utm_medium=organic&utm_source=google_rich_qa&utm_campaign=google_rich_qa)