# Eclipse | Permission denied when trying to open sh file under Ubuntu

Tags: java, eclipse, ubuntu

I develop plug-in that works under Ubuntu. The plug-in is required to install a third party software with which it works.
Installation directory is "user home" [System.getProperty("user.home")]

After installation, when I try to open the executable file from this third party software is throwing an exception -

> java.io.IOException: Cannot run program >/home/mbaev/Tools/flasher/1.5.0/lua5.1.sh": error=13, Permission denied"

Where should be installed a third party software? Why this directory have permissions by default?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are probably two reasons：

1. lua5.1.sh is not executable. You can make it executable by setting:

`sudo chmod +x /home/mbaev/Tools/flasher/1.5.0/lua5.1.sh`

And then run it:

`./home/mbaev/Tools/flasher/1.5.0/lua5.1.sh`

2. If lua5.1.sh is executable but still says `error=13, Permission denied`. Maybe in this shell some of operations need root permission. Try to run it by sudo:

`sudo ./home/mbaev/Tools/flasher/1.5.0/lua5.1.sh`

Comment: While `sudo` will no doubt run the script, it should not be applied too eagerly. We do not know what the script will do.

Comment: But I want to programmatically unarchive the third party software in user home dir and then start the .sh file programmatically without need any permissions, this is possible?

Comment: @MBaev then you need to set the file executable programmatically. https://stackoverflow.com/a/664443/3908814

Comment: I resolved this problem with permission settings. Thank you @Bejond

Answer (score 0):

This might also belong to [Ask Ubuntu](https://askubuntu.com).

Anyway, in order to run a script on linux, you need to have access rights to the directory the script is in, and **execute rights** set on the script. Most likely you are missing the **exec rights**.

The command

```
chmod u+x <myscript.sh>
```

Will add execute rights for the current user. Try that first.