# java- How do programmatically change user to root before changing file permissions?

Tags: java, file-permissions

In Java, I would like to dynamically change the file permission of a Linux file. I have tried to set it with Files.setPosixFilePermissions as suggested from this other source: [How do I programmatically change file permissions?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/664432/how-do-i-programmatically-change-file-permissions), but I am getting the error

> java.nio.file.FileSystemException: : Operation not permitted

I figured out that I am unable to set the file permissions as a user, since the file is owned by root. My question is: Is it possible to execute Files.setPosixFilePermissions by switching from user to root in java? And then switching back to user when done?

Here is the bulk of my code:

```
String path = "/usr/local/bin/driver";
try {
  Utility.setAsExecutable(path);
} catch (IOException e) {
  logger.error("Unable to set driver as executable.");
  e.printStackTrace();
}

  public static void setAsExecutable(String filePath) throws IOException {

    // using PosixFilePermission to set file permissions 755
    Set<PosixFilePermission> perms = new HashSet<PosixFilePermission>();
    perms.add(PosixFilePermission.OWNER_READ);
    perms.add(PosixFilePermission.OWNER_WRITE);
    perms.add(PosixFilePermission.OWNER_EXECUTE);

    perms.add(PosixFilePermission.GROUP_READ);
    perms.add(PosixFilePermission.GROUP_EXECUTE);

    perms.add(PosixFilePermission.OTHERS_READ);
    perms.add(PosixFilePermission.OTHERS_EXECUTE);

    Files.setPosixFilePermissions(Paths.get(filePath), perms);
    logger.info("Modified as executable " + filePath);

  }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no way to change the owner of a running process (be it a JVM or anything else).

You can however spawn a new, privileged process to do the "dirty" work.