# How to add an executable file to an AWS Lambda .jar on windows?

Tags: windows, amazon-web-services, selenium, aws-lambda

I want to use Selenium in an AWS Lambda. So I packaged the necessary files into a .jar file and uploaded it to S3. The Lambda terminates with the error: "The driver is not executable: /var/task/lib/chromedriver".

I think I am supposed to run 'chmod 777' on the chromedriver before packaging it into the .jar-file. But I am developing on windows, so this is not possible. Is it possible to add an executable file to an AWS Lambda .jar on windows?

Comment: Can you explicitly run chmod via one of the solutions at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/664432/how-do-i-programmatically-change-file-permissions before attempting to run Selenium?

Comment: Setting permissions after uploading the .jar causes: "errorMessage": "/var/task/lib/chromedriver.exe: Read-only file system".

Comment: https://superuser.com/questions/213774/is-there-an-archive-tool-that-runs-on-windows-that-i-can-set-the-execute-attr/213782