# Read a File without Checkmarx warning

Tags: java, file, checkmarx

I am trying to read a file stored in filesystem in Java using the below code.

```
byte[] readAllBytes = null;
File templateFile = new File("/myfolder/abc.png");
readAllBytes = Files.readAllBytes(templateFile.toPath());
```

While scanning this code in Checkmarx tool, the tool raises an issue of "Incorrect Permission Assignment For Critical Resources" . I have referred [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62563078/fixing-incorrect-permission-assignment-for-critical-resources-cwe-732) about this issue and understand that it is about creating a file with the correct permissions so that it is not misused. But here, I am not creating a file, but I am reading a file. In this case how will I resolve this issue in Checkmarx?

Answer (score 0):

```
File tempFile = File.createTempFile(TEMP_FILE_PREFIX,TEMP_FILE_SUFFIX, new File(TEMP_FOLDER));
FileWriter fw = new FileWriter(tempFile);
tempFile.setExecutable(false);
tempFile.setReadable(true);
tempFile.setWritable(true);
fw.write(CONTENT);

this shld help, post that u can raise mitigation request with security team.
```

Comment: Isnt this for creating a new file? I am actually reading an existing file?