# How to set file read-only to not be able to change this setting by Java

Tags: java, file, readonly

By using `File.setReadOnly()`, I can make the file read-only; however, user can still change this setting by right-clicking the file.

Is there any way to lock this movement?

I've tried both `File.setReadable()` and `File.setWritable()`, none of them worked.

Comment: Changing if the file is "readable" and administration rights for certain groups/users are two different things.

Comment: Does it mean we can't change the right for certain groups/users of a file by java?

Comment: You might want to start here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/664432/how-do-i-programmatically-change-file-permissions